# Htaccess Rewrite for name/value pair

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite, url-rewriting

I need some help to write a dynamic rule where i can add name/value pair separated by '/' instead of name1=value&name2=value2

e.g

http://www.example.com/jeans.html?color=24&manufacturer=3
http://www.example.com/jeans/color/black/manufacturer/jonh-miller.html

&

http://www.example.com/jeans.html?color=24&manufacturer=3&size=1
http://www.example.com/jeans/color/black/manufacturer/jonh-miller/size/xl.html

and so on.
can any one point me to some good documentation ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use RewriteMap

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewritemap

You should first match the parameters then use the maps, for example:

```
RewriteMap my_redir_map1 txt:map_rewrite.txt
RewriteMap my_redir_map2 txt:map_rewrite.txt

RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\bcolor\b=(\w+|&\w+;)+)
RewriteCond %{QUERY_STRING} ^.*(\bmanufacturer\b=(\w+|&\w+;)+)
RewriteRule ^/([^/\.]+).html /$1/color/${my_redir_map1:%1}/manufacturer/${my_redir_map2:%2}.html  [L]
```

This should match the case:

http://www.example.com/jeans.html?color=24&manufacturer=3

and rewrite it to:

http://www.example.com/jeans/color/black/manufacturer/jonh-miller.html

Please note: This solution needs a map for each parameter and a rewrite for each final path.